How to determine the intervals in which a function (which is a sum of two trigonometric functions) is positive.
I was trying to solve the following problem:
Find the intervals in which the function f given by
$f(x) = \sin x + \cos x,~0 \le x\le 2 \pi$
is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.
My approach was as follows:
Step I: Finding the derivative.
$f'(x) = \cos x - \sin x $
Step II: Finding the points at which the derivative is zero.
By equating $f'(x)$ to zero, and solving the trigonometric equation, I was able to show that, the derivative becomes zero at $\frac{\pi}{4}~\text{and}~\frac{5 \pi}{4}$.
So the domain can be divided into three parts AC, CD and DB as shown below:

Step III: Finding the intervals where $f'(x)$ is positive and finding the intervals where $f'(x)$ is negative.
My doubt is regarding this step. The text book says that:
(i) $f'(x)$ is positive in the interval $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{4} \right) \cup \left(\frac{5 \pi}{4}, 2 \pi \right]$.
(ii) $f'(x)$ is negative in the interval $\left(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{5 \pi}{4} \right)$.
The text book does not say how the above two results are obtained. So I tried my own method. First I wrote $f'(x)$ as the product of two trigonometric functions:
\begin{array}{ll}  &{\color{magenta}1} &{} &{f’(x)} &{}={} &{\cos x - \sin x} &{} \\
&{\color{magenta}2} &{} &{{}} &{}={} &{\cos x - \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} – x \right)} &{} \\
&{\color{magenta}3} &{} &{{}} &{}={} &{-2 \sin \left(\frac{x + \pi/2 - x}{2} \right) \sin \left(\frac{x - \pi/2 + x}{2} \right)} &{} \\
&{\color{magenta}4} &{} &{{}} &{}={} &{-2 \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4} \right) \sin \left(x - \frac{\pi}{4} \right)} &{} \\
&{\color{magenta}5} &{} &{{}} &{}={} &{-2 \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \right) \sin \left(x - \frac{\pi}{4} \right)} &{} \\
&{\color{magenta}6} &{} &{{}} &{}={} &{-{\sqrt 2} \sin \left(x - \frac{\pi}{4} \right)} &{} \\
\end{array}
Now I can analyse the three intervals:
(i) When x is taken from the interior of AC, it will be less than $\frac{\pi}{4}$.
So $(x - \frac{\pi}{4})$ is negative.
$\implies \sin(x - \frac{\pi}{4})$ is negative.
$\implies -\sqrt{2}\sin(x - \frac{\pi}{4})$ is positive.
(ii) When x is taken from the interior of CD, it will be between $\frac{\pi}{4}~\text{and}~\frac{5 \pi}{4}$.
So $(x - \frac{\pi}{4})$ will be between zero and $\pi$.
$\implies \sin(x - \frac{\pi}{4})$ is positive.
$\implies -\sqrt{2}\sin(x - \frac{\pi}{4})$ is negative.
(iii) When x is taken from the interior of DB, it will be between $\frac{5 \pi}{4}~\text{and}~2 \pi$.
So $(x - \frac{\pi}{4})$ will be between $\pi$ and $\frac{7 \pi}{4}$.
$\implies \sin(x - \frac{\pi}{4})$ is negative.
$\implies -\sqrt{2}\sin(x - \frac{\pi}{4})$ is positive.
I would like to know whether an easier method is available to find the signs of this $f'(x)$ in the different intervals. Please share your thoughts.

You should be able to use a unit circle diagram to find, visually, intervals where $\cos x - \sin x > 0$, they are just the intervals where $\cos x > \sin x$ (which are the points on the circle below the line $y=x$)

We have $$f(x)=2\sin(\pi/4)\cos(x -\pi/4)=\sqrt{2}\cos(x -\pi/4)$$ Thus $f(x)$ is decreasing on $\pi/4\le x\le 3\pi/4$ and increasing on $3\pi/4\le x\le 7\pi/4.$ By periodicity it is increasing on $0\le x\le \pi/4.$

Since the derivative is continuous and is zero at $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{5\pi}{4}$, then those two values are the only values on $\left[0,2\pi\right)$ at which the derivative can change from positive to negative or vice versa. Thus, those two values split $\left[0,2\pi\right)$ into three intervals in which the derivative must be strictly positive or strictly negative. You can choose any value in each of those intervals and substitute your chosen values into the derivative to determine if the derivative is positive or negative on each interval. For example, on the interval $\left(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)$, arbitrarily choose $\pi$. The derivative at $\pi$ is
$$f'(\pi)=\cos\pi-\sin\pi=-1-0=-1<0.$$
Since the derivative is negative for just one value in the interval $\left(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)$, the derivative must be negative for all values in $\left(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)$; hence, $f(x)$ is decreasing on that interval. Again, this is because there were no points in that interval in which the function had a derivative equal to 0; therefore, there were no points at which the function could transition from decreasing to increasing or vice versa.
You could check the interval $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ by evaluating $f'\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$, and you could check the interval $\left(\frac{5\pi}{4},2\pi\right]$ by evaluating $f'\left(\frac{11\pi}{6}\right)$. The work to check each interval is as follows:
$$f'\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}>0.$$
$$f'\left(\frac{11\pi}{6}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{11\pi}{6}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}>0.$$
Since the derivative is positive at each of those values, it must be positive at all values in the intervals from which those values were chosen. Hence, $f(x)$ is increasing on those intervals.
